# Trying to query a table in a mysql db using input from a csv file (Only have read permissions on the mysql db)

Tags: mysql

I have read access to this database which I want to query. I have a csv file which contains a list of ids. I want to query the database and find all documents with the ids listed in the csv file. The normal way, I believe, I would go about doing this is to import the csv file as a table or as a new column. However, I only have read permissions, and I don't believe I can get my permissions changed. As such, I cannot change any of the tables or add any new tables.

So there is 1000 or so lines in the csv file. Typing in all the ids manually into a query isn't really an option. But I also can't import the csv file. Is there some solution that would allow me to look for and find all relevant entries (entries whose id matches an id in the csv file).

Comment: Most likely you'll have access to create a temporary table but you may or may not have access to insert values into that temp table.  If you did you could do a basic sql script inserting the csv info and then using the ID values in a WHERE IN for your table you're trying to filter.

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Temp1 ( Name Char( 30 ), seqid integer );

Assuming this is how you create a temporary table correctly... I was denied access :(

Comment: Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'user_name'@'%' to database 'database_name' Specifically is the error I got

Comment: Can you write a script in PHP, Python, Perl, etc.?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to write a Python script or something because I didn't want to go through all the hassle of setting up mysql with Python just for this one query. But it looks like that may be what I have to do.

Comment: Only 2 ways I can think of: 1) use notepad and do find `new line` character replace with `,` and filter id using `IN` 2) dump and download the entire table and clean up on your local machine

Comment: I eventually just did it all in Notepad. Surprisingly painless. Thanks guys!